# css calculation of the width

Tags: css, wordpress

I got into a math problem

my content box is 700pc wide
my hentry (inside content) is 100% wide with padding of 10px

wich make the hentry to be wider that the content resulting and overflow...

Any solution

Here is the page : http://www.equipe94.com

I have firebug and removing the width 100% work, but it send by wordpress so how to overwrite a width:100% with nothing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.hentry {
width: auto;
}

Answer (score 0):

Or this way: If you have a padding of `10px` then your inside content box must have a width of

```
700px - 2 * 10px = 680px
```